# A\(B∩C) = (A\B) ∪ (A\C) how to prove?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that. While I know this is true by thinking about it I'm having a lot of trouble actually writing the proof

Comment: Should the right hand side be $(A \setminus B) \cap (A\setminus C)$?

Comment: @Matt no, see e.g. De Morgan's rules.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Oops. Yes, in my head I was thinking $x\in B\cap C$ rather than $x\not\in B\cap C$.  Never do math before finishing your coffee!

Comment: Prove that A\(B∩C) = (A\B) ∪ (A\C) for arbitrary sets A, B.
this is how question given to me sir

Comment: In general, proving equality of two sets $A$ and $B$, requires to show $A  \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ that is to show $\forall x \in A, x \in B$ and similarly, $\forall x \in B, x \in A$

Comment: Have a look at [de morgan law $A\setminus (B \cap C) = (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/597499) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/597499).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you  its very useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select a point $x \in A \setminus (B \cap C)$.

Then $x \in A$, but $x \notin B \cap C$.

The latter condition means that either $x \notin B$ or $x \notin C$ (since it does not belong to both $B$ and $C$). Thus either $x \in A \setminus B$ or $x \in A \setminus C$. That is, $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$.

Look at the implication that was just proved: $$x \in A \setminus (B \cap C) \implies x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C).$$ This is precisely the meaning of $A \setminus (B \cap C) \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$.

It remains to prove that $ (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C) \subseteq A \setminus (B \cap C)$. You can take it from here.

Comment: thank you for clear answer sir   :)