# Is it true that $X\setminus (A\cap B) = X\setminus A \cup X\setminus B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

While proving something I used an identity that I checked by *logical thinking* and Venn Diagrams:
$$X\setminus (A\cap B) = X\setminus A \cup X\setminus B$$
Is this identity true?

Comment: Yes: I suppose that you have to prove it...

Comment: Just to avoid any ambiguity: $X\setminus(A\cap B)=(X\setminus A)\cup(X\setminus B)$.

Comment: __logical thinking__ can be dangerous. If you are in the first semester, you should prove it. It isn't very hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [de morgan law $A\setminus (B \cap C) = (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597499/de-morgan-law-a-setminus-b-cap-c-a-setminus-b-cup-a-setminus-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general method, if you want to prove that two given sets, $S_1, S_2$ are equal, you need to show that
$$ S_1 \subseteq S_2 \quad \wedge \quad S_2 \subseteq S_1 $$

How do we prove such inclusions? let's take your example. We want to show that
$$ X \setminus (A \cap B) \subseteq (X \setminus A) \cup (X \setminus B) $$
To do this, we take $ x \in X \setminus (A \cap B)$. So, by definition $x \in X$ and $x \notin A \cap B$. Then we can have two cases:

1. $x \notin A$, so remembering that $x \in X$ we have $x \in X \setminus A$ and so $x \in (X \setminus A) \cup (X \setminus B)$
2. $x \notin B$, so as before $x \in X$ implies $x \in X \setminus B$ and so $x \in (X \setminus A) \cup (X \setminus B)$

So we can conclude that the inclusion is true, since all the elements in the first set belong to the second.

**Exercise** try to prove the second inclusion

Answer (score 1):

This is basically De Morgan's Law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra

Which is a common result and maybe you already proofed it. You might check that first.

$X\setminus (A\cap B)=(A\cap B)^c\stackrel{DML}{=} A^c\cup B^c=X\setminus A\cup X\setminus B$