# If $A, B$ and $C$ are sets, then $A - (B \cap C) = (A - B) \cup (A - C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

If $A, B$ and $C$ are sets, then $A - (B \cap C) = (A - B) \cup (A - C)$

I'm a bit confused on the correct way to start this proof. Should I start it: Suppose, $x \in A, B$ and $C$? Then work through the definitions until I prove both sides?

What is some general guidance on including an element in a set when you're constructing one of these set proofs?

If I were to start the proof out as follows $x \in (A - (B \cap C))$. How do i specify what set contains $x$?

Comment: You could do that: if $x \in A \cap B \cap C$ is it in the left hand side? is it in the right hand side?  What about $y \in A \cap B \cap C^c$?  What about $z \in A \cap B^c \cap C^c$? What other possibilities are worth considering?

Comment: You should try to pick $x\in A- (B\cap C)$ and see if this implies $x\in (A-B)\cap (A-C).$ And then the other way around

Comment: If you know how unions and intersections distribute, then the easiest way might be two write (A-B) in terms of intersections and compliments and go from there.

Comment: by the way, is there a typo in the claim? It is not true as stated.

Comment: There is no typo. @GiulioRicci That's what I was originally thinking my textbook says to put the element inside the left hand side ($x \in A - (B \cap C$)), but it just feels wrong to me for some reason? Like I'm not being explicit enough.

Comment: I assume $A-B$ means $A \cap B^c$? In that case taking as subsets of the natural numbers $A = \{1, 4, 3, 5\}$, $B = \{3, 4, 1\}$ and $C = \{5, 2, 1\}$ shows the claim to be false.

Comment: @Ziggy the intersection on the RHS should be a union. Then the claim is true.

Comment: @Enforce i fixed it. You are correct. I apologies.

Comment: "$x \in (A - (B \cap C))$" IS specifying what set contains $x$.

Comment: @AnneBauval i did look for duplicates and couldn't find any.

Comment: (link in next comment found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24A%20-%20(B%20%5Ccap%20C)%20%3D%20(A%20-%20B)%20%5Ccup%20(A%20-%20C)%24&p=1)) See also [proof of $ A - \left (B \cap C \right)= \left (A - B \right) \cup \left (A - C \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449560)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [de morgan law $A∖(B∩C)=(A∖B)∪(A∖C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597499) And [A\ (B∩C) = (A\B) ∪ (A\C) how to prove?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101653)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it as shown below.
If $x∈(A−B∩C)$, then $$(x∈A) \wedge  (x \notin  B \ \text{  or }\ x \notin  C)$$
If $x∈(A−B)\cup (A-C)$, then $$[ (x∈A)\wedge(x \notin  B)] \quad or  \quad [(x∈A)\wedge(x \notin  C)] $$
it means $(x∈A) \wedge  (x \notin  B \ \text{  or }\ x \notin  C)$.We can find
$$ x∈(A−B∩C)  \Leftrightarrow x∈(A−B)\cup (A-C) $$
Then we prove $A−B∩C=(A−B)\cup (A-C)$.